# Can Hadoop's Shuffle/Sort (or partition) phase be customized to perform a graph traversal?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, partitioning, graph-traversal

I am still learning about the MapReduce framework, specifically implemented by Hadoop, and I wonder if it can be modified to perform the following task:

The Map() function will emit (key,value) pairs, whose keys are arrays of size 2, say int[2].
I would like every pair containing any of the two integers in common to be mapped to the same reducer.

So for example, if Map() emits: ([2,3],4),([2,4],5),([6,5],2),([5,7],1), then Reduce1 should receive the first two pairs, and Reduce2 the second two (first two sharing 2, second two sharing 5).
This can be viewed as a connected component problem, where the vertices are the integers in the int[], and edges are shared between any two integers in the same int[].

Comment: The keys (e.g., [2,3] and [2,4]) are not identical so the values are not passed together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A change in algorithm and you can probably achieve this - but you're going to need emit each edge twice

For each edge you currently output, you should output them for both vertex IDs, amend the outputted value to include the other edge, the weight and optionally a direction (if edge direction is important to your algorithm).

So instead of this:

```
([2,3],4)
([2,4],5)
([6,5],2)
([5,7],1)
```

Output this (S denotes the key was the source, D denotes the key was the destination):

```
(2, [3, 4, S])
(3, [2, 4, D])
(2, [4, 5, S])
(4, [2, 5, D])
(6, [5, 2, S])
(5, [6, 2, D])
(5, [7, 1, S])
(7, [5, 1, D])
```

Now in your reducer, you'll be grouping by the vertex ID, and will be able to iterate other the tuples containing the other vertex ID, a weight, and the direction:

```
(2, [3, 4, S])
(2, [4, 5, S])

(3, [2, 4, D])

(4, [2, 5, D])

(5, [6, 2, D])
(5, [7, 1, S])

(6, [5, 2, S])

(7, [5, 1, D])
```

You still need to be aware that each edge could potentially be processed twice, especially if the edges exist in both directions between two vertices.

Comment: I did think of something similar, but the problem is that having two copies each of edge will add a serious difficulty to the process I had in mind. I appreciate the in depth explanation because if i choose to go this route, it will be quite useful. But you don't think there is a way to change the Shuffle/Sort as I had described?
Ideally, each edge would be assigned to a unique Reducer.

Comment: Well you could create a custom partitioner that compares the two vertex IDs and return the hash of lesser of the two, but then you won't get both edges if you have [1,3] and [3,4] for example. There really isn't a way around this other than emitting the edges twice

Comment: Sorry for the redundancy, but can the partitioner not "seek" for keys?
As in, if each edge was outputted twice, with the added condition that the other vertex connected by each edge is present in the "value" of the pair, i.e.:
`(2, [3,4])
(3, [2,4])`
(as you had done in your answer, for the original ([2,3],4))
Can the partitioner not look at the first pair, retrieve its first 'value,' and then seek for all keys '3' and send those to the same reducer, iteratively performing this for each emitted pair?
I'm still not quite sure what is preventing this from being done.

Comment: Using '3' as the key in subsequent chaining would introduce ambiguity; e.g., if an edge exists between 3 and 8. Given O(n^2) edges as it is, why does writing each edge twice introduce "serious difficulty"?

Comment: Why would an edge existing between 3 and 8 be ambiguous? The goal is to group together all connected vertices. So if there is an edge between 3 and 8, it should be identified.
And there are only n/2 edges, if n is the number of vertices. Originally, each edge connects exactly 2 vertices, so there are precisely half as many edges. And if each edge is written twice, then in my desired reduce phase, it will be connected to two disjoint graphs. Essentially, these graphs will be agglomerated into one new node, and so an edge should only be in one Reduce.

Comment: @JimPrahn the partitioner cannot seek, it's presented a K,V pair and asked which reducer it should be sent to. You could retain state in either the mapper or the paritioner, but you'll still have problems if the state exceeds the available memory, or you're in more than a single mapper

Comment: Duly noted, thank you. Alternatively, can the map emissions be written to the HDFS, processed manually and tagged with some new key representing the desired grouping for reducers, and then inputted back to the partitioner with the new keys? Evidently this would be quite computationally expensive, but I'm just wondering if it is feasible.

Comment: Sure, just chain multiple jobs together